# JetBrain CLion - what is add to target?

Tags: clion

Start using CLion. Trying to create a example toy code in a newly created blank project by adding a new cpp file. It shows the window.

[image]

Just click OK and gets the warning.

[image]

Which documents under [CLion 2023.2 document - Configure projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/project.html) or [Clion - Quick Start Guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/clion-quick-start-guide.html) explain what should have been done and what this warning mean?

According to [Setting build target in CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801836/setting-build-target-in-clion), it seems I need manually setup CMakeLists.txt but not sure where in the document it is explained.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(test)
```